# How do I install Marathon on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Ok, so updating my question, maybe this'll help...

I'm trying to install [Marathon](http://marathon.sourceforge.net/games/marathon2.php#download), on this page it says to unpack the tar.bz2 file and run (I'm assuming this means in Terminal)

```
./configure && make && make install
```

but it returns as,

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Not sure what to do here

Comment: Ok, I updated the question

Comment: Are you running those commands from the location where you unpacked that file? You'll need to `cd` to the directory where the source archive has been extracted. See [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) for details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal and navigate to the folder where you saved the file:

   ```
   cd /home/$USER/<my_marathon_download_folder>
   ```
2. Extract the archive with this command:

   ```
   tar xf AlephOne-20140104.tar.bz
   ```
3. Change the folder again:

   ```
   cd AlephOne-20140104
   ```
4. Now you can start with `./configure`:

   ```
   ./configure
   ```

   This command is likely to fail with an error because you'll probably have to install some libraries. But since I do not know your system, I can not tell you which libraries are.

   In my case I need, for example, the development library for SDL:

   ```
   checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... no
   ```

   These can be installed with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
   ```